# Erro Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded:

Tags: mysql, docker

sou novato no mundo da programação. Estou com o seguinte problema:
Instalei o Sequeler e ao criar uma conexão, retorna o seguinte erro:

< Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /app/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so:
não é possível abrir arquivo compartilhado: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente >

os procedimentos realizado no docker não retornaram nenhum erro.

Para tentar corrigir, já realizei os seguintes procedimentos que não deram certo:

```
< ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Senha123';>
<  mv /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.bak 
   /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
   Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) >
< updatedb >
< locate apache2.conf >
< locate -i apache2.conf >
< locate -S >
< find /etc -name apache2.conf >
< find / -iname apache2.conf >
< apt-file update >
< apt-file search crack.h >
```

e sempre o mesmo erro.

Podem ajudar?

Grato

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Ok. realizei os seguintes procedimentos: acesso o sequeler para criar uma nova conexao. informo o nome do meu container: Mysql-A; o database type:: Mysql; o host: 192.168...; database name: aula; username: root; paswd: ***; porta: 3306, mas ao mandar conectar aparece o erro: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /app/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so:
não é possível abrir arquivo compartilhado: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente. E ja tentei varios passos e não resolveram.... Como faço. estou perdido

Answer (score -3):

Olá, você pode ir no seu arquivo "my.cnf" e adicionar a seguinte linha abaixo do [mysqld].

**default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password**

Agora, reinicie o serviço do mysql e refaça a query de alteração.

**ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Senha123';**